# How to disable ListView reload items when change page on Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp

I'm using Xamarin.Forms for UWP.

I have 2 page, And I need to switch them some time:

```
// Change main page
App.Current.MainPage = otherPage; // this is not a new page, already exists 
// Navigate
App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(otherPage); // this is not a new page, already exists
// Change detail page
MasterDetailsPage.Detail = otherPage; // this is not a new page, already exists
```

page, just switch between 2 pages.

the `otherPage` is the page already finish load. This is the example for this page:

```
  public partial class Page1 : ContentPage
    {
        public Page1 ()
        {
            InitializeComponent ();

            ObservableCollection<StateModel> strList = new ObservableCollection<StateModel>();
            for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++)
            {
                strList.Add(new StateModel() { Price = i, ProductName = "Product  " + i });
            }

           btn.Clicked += (sender, args) =>
           {
              // change to another page which already finish load
              App.Current.MainPage = StaticPage.Page2;
          };

        }

    }
```

This is the XAML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="App1.Page1">

  <Grid>
    <StackLayout>
      <Label  Margin="6,20,0,0" Text="scroll items and click go to other page and return you will find the listview reset: scroll on the top(I only change the App.Current.MainPage, not create new page)"/>

      <Button x:Name="btn" Text="Go" />

      <ListView x:Name="lvList"  Margin="0,10,0,0" ItemsSource="{Binding }" IsRefreshing="False">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
              <Grid Padding="10" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                  <ColumnDefinition/>
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Label Text="{Binding ProductName}" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
                <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Price}" Margin="10,0" />
                <Label Text="" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" Margin="0,0,10,0">
                  <Label.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger TargetType="Label" Binding="{Binding Price}" Value="90">
                      <Setter Property="Text" Value=">>>>>"/>
                    </DataTrigger >
                  </Label.Triggers>
                </Label>
              </Grid>
            </ViewCell>
          </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
      </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
  </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

But it will always reload the ListView items when change the page, the items added one by one(just like some kind of animation)

Like every time the ListView show on when switch pages, it will do :

```
ListView.Clear();
ListView.Add();
ListView.Add();
ListView.Add();
// -- continue add 100 items --
```

That will make the page load speed very slow, a big performance problem to me. Also it will lost scroll position before I scrolled, it will scroll to top(because it clear and add all item again.), also I don't know last time which item I'm selected, it will lost.

Is there anyway to fix it?  Thank you.

**Update**:

```
public static class StaticPage
{
        public static Page1 Page1;
        public static Page2 Page2;


        public static void Init()
        {
            Page1 = new Page1();
            Page2 = new Page2();
        }
}
```

Some friend need this that's why I add it.
Why I use it because just for let you understand, I never reload the ListView items manually,  I only create the page once.

Comment: If you use MasterDetailPage why do you wannt change the whole App.MainPage if someone tap on an ListViewItem? Use MasterDetailPage.Detail = new NavigationPage(new Foo()); And on Item tap just make a Navigation.PushAsync(new BarWhichDependsOnItem());

Comment: @Nitro.de Hi friend. Looks like you're not understand.  I never said I only change whole `App.MainPage`, if you see it clearly, you will found there is also has `MasterDetails.Detail=`

Comment: If you want to hide the MasterDetailPage-Menu after the button is tapped just use Navigation.PushModalAsync so the MasterDetail is hide until you popModal again

Comment: I see it but `App.Current.MainPage = StaticPage.Page2;` is what i dont understand

Comment: @Nitro.de. I can't use navigation. because that's different details. I can't use navigation change between these page.  About the `StaticPage` I'll add the code

Comment: Did you try to set another [CachingStrategy](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.ListViewCachingStrategy/) in the Listview?

Comment: @Nitro.de Yes. No any different.

Comment: you could enable caching for your pages. In the XAML code set `NavigationCacheMode="Enabled"` or `Required` for more details [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.page.navigationcachemode(v=vs.95).aspx). This way the loaded page will be cached you can navigate between the two cached pages without the need of reloading them. If you _want_ to reload them you have to handle this in the `OnNavigatedTo` event in the code-behind.

Comment: @TryToSolveItSimple We are toking about `Xamarin.Forms` friend.

Comment: then can you do something like [this](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/master/Navigation/MasterDetailPage/WinPhone81/MainPage.xaml.cs)? Move my mentioned code to the code-behind.

Comment: @TryToSolveItSimple I just try to add it to MainPage on UWP project. but no any different with my code.`App.Current.MainPage = somePage`

Comment: Where you you set the BindingContext of the Page? I also find it a bit strange that you use just {Binding} for the ItemSource without any property. If you use Bindings why do you populate an array inside a Pages Constructor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it is a **bug** from  Xamarin.Forms.

See details:

[ScrollViewer will reset the scroll position when navigate to exists page or back to the last page](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=48682)

[UWP phone Navigate to exist page still very slow.](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=46856)

Already more than 1 year, Even someone did send pull request for fixing it, Xamarin team did not merge the code. Maybe Xamarin team already know Windows Phone will dead few years ago.